# Move image to another div with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

I'm new with Wordpress, and this is my first Wordpress site, so bear with me please.

This is my index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
   <div id="content">
        <section id="posts">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <section class="post">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>        </a></h2>
                    <div class="holder">

                    </div>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </section>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
     <p><?php _e('Nothing here, sorry.'); ?></p>
     <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </aside>
         <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>   
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
</div>  
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Basically, what I want is to find first image from a post, and place it inside the .holder div. It should work similar to detach() and append() in jQuery.

I know that I should use filters and actions, but I have no idea how to start, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why dont you just echo out the image inside of your holder did instead of trying to move it around

Comment: @DavidChase
As I said, I'm new to it, so can you explain me how to do it, or write me a piece of code?

Comment: What you could do is set a "Featured Image" do you know about this function?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't really work for me.

Comment: do you want the holder div contain multiple first images from posts?

Comment: @DavidChase
No, just one image from the appropriate post. Kinda like a thumbnail.

Comment: you said you used this function correct? `$id = get_the_ID(); echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, $size_of_image_here);`

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file functions.php :

```
<?php function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

if(empty($first_img)){ 
 //Defines a default image
 $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
}
return $first_img;
}
?>
```

and in your file index.php place this :

```
<div class="holder">
   <img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the .holder only shows img src, not the actual image.

Comment: Just added 
<img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" /> to the .holder (instead of <?php echo catch_that_image() ?>), and everything works perfectly, thanks.